# How do I search contacts using email address rather than name?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, livechattranscript

During live chat our customers can talk to CS agents without logging in, hence we cannot capture customer information using pre-chat form.
Now the problem is we cannot search the customers using their email address but only by their name so searching for John Doe will give 200+ results and there is no way to know which one is the correct one
Attaching screenshot of the area I am referring to
When we click on Contact Name or Account Name and type email address, it gives 0 results and with name 200+ results and users will never know which one is correct.
Is there a workaround/solution for it?

[image: Live Agent Screenshot]

Comment: Using global search should return your result set. Let me know if it worked

Comment: Sorry, global search is not a viable solution as it will take user to another page, however, if it helps, I checked with salesforce CS and they said it cannot be done.